# How can I tell if a GKE autopilot workload is running on a Spot Pod?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I've tried the following, but though it lists the Node Selectors that show cloud.google.com/gke-spot=true, it doesn't describe anything more explicit about whether it's running on a Spot Pod:

```
kubectl describe pod/nginx-2-deployment-#########-##### -n my-namespace
```

Answer (score 2):

**Below are the 3 possible scenarios to check the autopilot workload is running on Spot Pod** :

1. As per this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-spot-pods#request-spot-pods), if you Specify
   `cloud.google.com/gke-spot=true` label in a nodeSelector or node
   affinity in your Pod specification or manifest then ***GKE
   automatically provisions nodes to run on spot pods only***.  This
   indicates that When you request Spot Pods, Autopilot automatically
   provisions Spot VMs, adds taints and tolerations, and manages
   autoscaling and scheduling.

When you use  [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) to require Spot Pods in a Deployment. You need to specify the `cloud.google.com/gke-spot=true` label to your Deployment.

When you use [node affinity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-spot-pods#use-node-affinity) to request Spot Pods, you can specify the type of node affinity to use, as follows:

- `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: Must use Spot Pods`.
- `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: Use Spot Pods on a best-effort basis`.

Check the manifest by using `**kubectl describe pod POD_NAME`** .
When you check the manifest if this label is in deployment then it indicates that the workload is running on spotpod only.

2. You can also use this [matchselector](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting?&_ga=2.169868513.-119854973.1680188008#matchnodeselector) to cross check the nodeselector labels

> To verify this, check the labels specified in the Pod specification's
> nodeSelector field, under spec: nodeSelector.
>
> To see how nodes in your cluster are labeled, run the following
> command:
>
> `kubectl get nodes --show-labels`
>
> To attach a label to a node, run the following command:
>
> `kubectl label nodes NODE_NAME LABEL_KEY=LABEL_VALUE`
>
> Replace the following:
>
> NODE_NAME: the desired node.
> LABEL_KEY: the label's key.
>
> LABEL_VALUE:the label's value.

3. Or else  By using this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-an-autopilot-cluster#gcloudhttps://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-an-autopilot-cluster#gcloud), you can also verify the cluster is running in autopilot mode. In GKE Autopilot clusters, Spot Pods are Pods that run on nodes backed by Compute Engine Spot VMs.

> To verify that your cluster is created in Autopilot mode, run the
> following command:
>
> `gcloud container clusters describe <CLUSTER_NAME>  --region <REGION>`
>
> The output contains the following: `autopilot:   enabled: true`